# Were there any improvements to the second Death Star (other than the change in exhaust port) that we know of?

Tags: star-wars, return-of-the-jedi

We know that the second Death Star was meant to have a different/non-existent exhaust port and when under construction it had a shield projected around it.

Other than these elements, one of which was planned to be totally temporary, do we know of any other improvements over its predecessor?

Did it have improved defences against one-man fighters? Did its laser charge more quickly? Did it have an upmarket cafeteria?

Comment: Garbage compactors had been replaced by more ecologically thoughtful compost heaps...

Comment: Well, it was much bigger, obviously

Comment: Related: https://youtu.be/zdukWtJwlPU?t=41s

Comment: @Ellesedil Love How It Should Have Ended!

Comment: ... and a new kitchen for the cafeteria featuring Jamaican cooking.

Comment: Canteen? https://youtu.be/Sv5iEK-IEzw

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is covered in the film's junior novelisation

> *However, it had none of the former Death Star’s design flaws. The
>   redesigned superlaser would require mere minutes — not hours — to be
>   recharged, and could be focused more finely, allowing it to fire at
>   moving targets, such as capital ships. With a projected diameter of
>   160 kilometers and a substantial increase in firepower, the new Death
>   Star would be not only larger than the original but also much more
>   lethal.*

And in the [Star Wars: Absolutely Everything You Need to Know](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1465437851)" factbook which indicates that the station has double the number of turbolasers along with a sizeable complement of ion cannons

[image]

Comment: Is there any reason it needed to be bigger? These things must have been half empty, surely?

Comment: @ThruGog - Lots more surface lasers. It's pretty much invulnerable to small fighters.

Comment: This is interesting about the superlaser. Where are the surface lasers mentioned, because they would make more sense. What a resource drain a Death Star is!

Comment: @ThruGog - They cost a trillion credits each, sufficient to build thousands of Star Destroyers.

Comment: Double the turbolasers! A wise decision.

Comment: I've got a fever.  And the only prescription... is more turbolasers!

Comment: @Nate - I can just imagine the planning meeting. **Planner #1** - *"So, Emperor Palpatine, we've designed it with 8000 turbolasers"*. **Palpatine:**  *"Make it 15000"* **Planner #1:**"*Sure thing, Boss*".

Comment: Planner#1's Spacebook status update:  The boss wants me to double the turbolasers.  Again.  #FML  (SpaceBook is Facebook, but in space.)

Comment: @Nate - He goes home to his space-wife and complains about his space-job as a space-architect.

Comment: @Valorum Hey, give him a space-break.  That space-job is space-hard.